# Return an SQLAlchemy datatype based on a Python datatype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I know there are functions that return a Python data type based on a SQLAlchemy data type. However, **is there a function which I can give a Python data type that returns me the appropriate SQLAlchemy data type?**

I currently use the following work around for this (target is a SQLite in-memory table):

```
def __get_dt_sqlalchemy_sqlite(self, python_object):
    """Convert Python data type to SQLite data type
    SQLite v3 data types:
        NULL        The value is a NULL value.
        INTEGER     The value is a signed integer, stored in 1,2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
        REAL        The value is a floating point value, stored asan 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
        TEXT        The value is a text string, stored using thedatabase encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
        BLOB        The value is a blob of data, stored exactly asit was input.
    """
    if python_object is None:
        return None
    elif isinstance(python_object, (int, bool)):
        return Integer()
    elif isinstance(python_object, float):
        return Float()
    elif isinstance(python_object, str):
        return String()
    else:
        print("[DbLookup] WARNING: Could not determine SQLite data type, using BLOB.")
        return LargeBinary()
```

Background:

I do this because I have a dataset based on a SQLAlchemy Textual query, for which I don't have the data types (related question: [Get data types from execute result in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304702/get-data-types-from-execute-result-in-sqlalchemy)).

If loop throught the columns of the first row of the dataset and call this function. If a column is None I scan up to the first 10 rows before I give up and assign it the String() data type.

I have the feeling that there are cleaner ways to do this... :|

Comment: This assumes there is a one-on-one mapping. For example, I'd not map `bool` to `Integer()`, I'd use `Boolean()` where appropriate. (Side note, `isinstance(True, int)` is true, no need to use `(int, bool)` as `bool` is a subclass of `int`). Others might want to use `Numeric`. These choices are usually *application specific*.

Comment: @Martijn. The application here is SQLite. There is indeed not a 1:1 mapping, that's why int and bool are both "cast" to int. I would expect that SQLAlchemy knows both the SQLite dialect and the appropriate Python data types and should in theory be able to provide a mapping function.

Comment: @Opsse. The question (in bold) is why it's posted here and not on Code Review. The code is mainly to help understand the question.

Comment: @svenema: yes, I know that this is sqlite, and the sqlite data type system is dynamic and has a limited range. That doesn't mean you can't layer a richer set of options on top with SQLAlchemy. SQLite doesn't really have a datetime time, but can treat strings as datetime values, and SQLAlchemy can build on that with a `DateTime` column. But you could also just treat the columns as strings. All this means that there is no one-on-one mapping.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Ah, yes I get your point. However the goal here is to get any SQLAlchemy data type, in order to create a Column object (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html), and all I have is a Python object. The function I'm looking for would return the most basic datatype. For example, given a Datetime, the function must return a String(), given that the context is SQLite.

Comment: Then just use a dictionary or a series of [single dispatch functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch); the latter handles subclasses where simple dictionary lookups can't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Good call these single dispatch functions. I didn't know about them. :D